# How to create instance object of a class that contains a generic type (using reflection)?

Tags: java

Using reflection, I need to create instance object of a class that contains a generic type.

To date, I'm struggling to find a solution.

I thank who can help me.

Example:

Class one:

```
package app;

public class PTRow {

}
```

Class two:

```
package app;

public class PTQuery<T extends PTRow> {

}
```

Class three. Here the problem:

```
package app;

public class PTConnection {

    public PTQuery<? extends PTRow> createQuery() {

        //TODO How implement this?

        return null;

    }

}
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

All generic types are converted to `java.lang.Object` upon compilation by a process called type *erasure*. So your nice strongly typed generics are all lost at runtime.

You'll need to use good old-fashioned polymorphism and factory pattern idioms.

Comment: Ok Bathsheba. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First note: using wildcard in generic type parameters is **not good practice for method return types**. You can of course use wildcards for parameter types.

Coming to your question: the return type you have declared makes it difficult to know what dynamic type to generate, if not for the type PTQuery.

As this is runtime, you could make the method generic, take in the class that is to be used as generic parameter:

```
public <T extends PTRow> PTQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> ptRowType){
    //And in here, all should be intuitive if you know your types...
}
```

Comment: Hi Ernest. Thanks. The your solution, answered me.

Comment: Finally looked like this:

 public <T extends PTRow> PTQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> ptRowType) 
  throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  
  PTQuery<T> query = new PTQuery<T>();
  
  //...
  
  return query;
  
 }